# Non-relativistic quark model, baryon masses and potential

Tags: quarks, strong-force, hadron-dynamics

Is there a simple non-relativistic quark model, based on which baryon masses, especially for the nucleon and the Delta resonance can be calculated?

What is a reasonable non-relativistic potential? Is there a potential similar to the heuristic quark-antiquark potential

$$V(r) \sim - \frac{\alpha(r)}{r} + kr$$

with 3-quark- and spin-terms?

Thanks.